# Irvine Assembly merge arrays

Tags: assembly, x86, masm, irvine32

I need to merge two arrays that are already sorted into another larger array, also in order. I can't use a sort. It assembles fine but won't display anything.

This is what I have so far. I'm new to this so go easy if its not the best.

```
include irvine32.inc
Title MergeArrays
.data
    a1 dw 1,3,4,7,9,15,17
    a2 dw 2,6,8,10,11,14,18,19
    a3 dw 15 dup(0)

.code
main proc
    sub EAX,EAX
    mov ESI,OFFSET a1
    mov EDI,OFFSET a2
    mov EDX,OFFSET a3
    mov ECX,lengthof a3 ;Set loop times

    call Merge
    call Display
    exit
    main endp
    jmp Endit

;=====================================================================
Merge proc
    TheLoop:
    TheJump:
    mov ax,[ESI]
    cmp ax,[EDI]
    jl AddA1        ;Jump if less
    jg AddA2        ;Jump if greater
    Loop TheLoop

    AddA1:
    mov ax,[ESI]
    mov [EDX],ax
    inc ESI
    inc EDX
    jmp TheJump

    AddA2:
    mov ax,[EDI]
    mov [EDX],ax
    inc EDI
    inc EDX
    jmp TheJump
Merge endp
;==================================================================
Display proc
    mov ECX,lengthof a3 ;Set loop times
    mov EDX,OFFSET a3

        DisplayLoop:
        mov ax,[EDX]
        call writedec
        call crlf
        inc EDX
        loop DisplayLoop
Display endp
;===================================================================


Endit:
end main
```

Comment: It does not display anything because the it never leaves the `merge` proc!!!  Where is the exit condition for the proc?  You basically have an endless loop... learn to use a debugger or better yet, create a debug macro that will print out values...

Comment: Thank you for the help. In class we just use a text editor. I should probably use a debugger. But doesn't ECX set the loop times? Wouldn't it stop after the length of a3 (array 3). Sorry for the dumb questions I'm new to all this.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

What happens when `TheLoop` is down to zero?  `ecx` becomes negative, exits the loop and then **KEEPS**  going to the next instruction which happens to be `AddA1` then back to `TheJump` then to either `AddA1` or `AddA2`, it is an infinite loop.  You need to add something after `Loop TheLoop` and before `AddA1` to exit the proc.

You don't really need a debugger, just something that will print passed values for debugging.

Comment: Thanks I knew it was going to be something simple. Aside from a few other issues it works. You've saved me hours of staring at the same thing.

Comment: The `Loop` instruction decrements _ECX_ first and the compares it to zero. If it is not zero it branches to the label given. If _ECX_ does become zero it drops out to the instruction after the `Loop` instruction. _ECX_ won't become negative, but it would be zero

Comment: And if _ECX_ was equal to zero before encountering the `Loop` instruction, in that case it would be decremented by 1 (becoming negative) and it would also jump to the label specified because _ECX_ was not equal to zero after the decrement).